# Start button starts a NSTimer, stop button stops it, start button starts it again. But 'invalidate' is giving me an error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have a start button which starts off a timer, declared in the .h file. Then I have a stop button which does `[theTimer invalidate];` and then when I go to start the timer again with the start button, it causes an error due to being invalidated.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: post an example of the code you are using.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak has the correct answer. You may get a more detailed answer, @Andrew, if you _post your code_.

Comment: check for the usage of the tag [xcode]: stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) is very specific on this point:
*Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.*

So, just create a new timer. If you do it only when user presses a button, it's not gonna kill your performance.

Comment: The problem with this is when i have a method which initialises it and a different method which invalidates it, the invalidating method doesn't recognise it if i initialise it in a different method. I'd have to initialise it in .h for it to recognise the NSTimer.

Comment: @Andrew 1) Maybe you can have a `BOOL enabled` variable to store whether timer is active or not and check it in action method. 2) Alternatively, you could create a simple wrapper for `NSTimer`. It could have `stop` and `resume` methods and retain timer creation parameters inside for later use in `resume`. I completely agree that `NSTimer` could offer more functionality, especially coming from java.

Comment: @Andrew Generally, posting some code might help, because I have trouble picturing your exact situation.

Answer (score 2):

The NSTimer class is a bit awkward to use; rather than separating the creation/destruction from the start/stop, it's all rolled together. In other words the timer starts as soon as it's created and stops as soon as it's destroyed.

You therefore need to use the existence of the NSTimer object as a flag to indicate if it's running; something like this:

// Private Methods

> @interface MyClass () 
>   {
>       NSTimer *_timer; 
>   }
>   - (void)_timerFired; 
>   @end
>
> @implementation MyClass
>
> - (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender 
>     {
>     if (_timer == nil)
>     {
>         _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
>                                                   target:self
>                                                 selector:@selector(_timerFired)
>                                                 userInfo:nil
>                                                  repeats:YES] retain];
>     } 
>     }
> - (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender 
>     {
>     if (_timer != nil)
>     {
>         [_timer invalidate];
>         _timer = nil;
>     } 
>     }
> - (void)_timerFired 
>     {
>     NSLog(@"ping"); 
>     }